# Greasemonkey facebook content manipulation

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

The goal is simple. Facebook doesn't allow animated gifs, what I am trying to achieve is that to upload an image (gifs) from the facebook wall, it will be changed to jpg and appears on the wall. The real gifs url will be added on the comment. The goal is to have a greasemonkey script with jquery, to get the a href attribute from the comment and set it as the image's src.

So far, my code is,

```
$("li>div.timelineUnitContainer")      
                    $("div.uiCommentContainer")
            var src = $a.attr("href");
                    unsafeWindow.console.log(src);
$('li>div.uiScaledImageContainer>photoUnit').has("img.img").attr('src',src);
```

I am not able to get the firebug console to show the log at line 4.

Thanks for your time.

Edit, i made it work, but this require the width of the image,

```
        var src = $("li>div.timelineUnitContainer div.uiCommentContainer [href]");
        var thumbObj = $('.uiScaledImageContainer.photoWrap').find('.img');
        var i;
        thumbObj.each(function() {
        var height = $(this).height();

        if (height==201)
        {
            $(this).attr('src',src[5]);

        }

        });
```

Comment: Did you specify `@grant unsafeWindow`?  Link to the **whole** script that you tried (use http://pastebin.com/, if needed) or edit it into your question if it's short enough (less than, about, 30 lines).  Also, edit the question to show a snippet of the HTML that contains the jpg and the link to the gif.  This must be exact and precise to ensure the script code works.

Comment: Thanks Brock, @grant unsafeWindow is new, thanks for sharing this. I have edited  the question, added a working code, tomorrow will show the html snippet and how it works now, and maybe if you have time show me the better ways.